# Desenvolvendo aplicação para comunicar com Scanner utilizando Windows image acquisition (WIA)

Tags: c, scanner

Estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação que comunique com uma Scanner. Em minhas pesquisas, encontrei na documentação da Microsoft um Serviço chamado Windows image acquisition que permite esta comunicação de uma aplicação com uma Scanner:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wia/-wia-startpage

Nesta documentação possui um tutorial de como comunicar com a Scanner através de codificação em C:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wia/-wia-creating-a-wia-device-manager

Como eu não tenho muito conhecimento em C eu tentei dar um Ctrl C Ctrl V, do código em minha IDE code blocks e tentei complilar para testar, mas sempre dá o mesmo erro:
error: unknown type name 'HRESULT'
Já tentei corrigir o erro buscando soluções na web, porém sem sucesso. Na verdade eu estou meio perdido, não sei muito o conceito da programação e não sei se está faltando alguma configuração ou algo similar para que o código rode.

Alguém poderia me auxiliar por gentileza? Me dar um horizonte por onde eu começo? ou como faço para rodar este código?

Desde já agradeço :)

Comment: o exemplo que você está querendo usar parece ser razoavelmente avançado, e como você mesmo diz que não tem muito conhecimento em C então acho que você não vai conseguir fazer funcionar; provavelmente você deveria procurar exemplos específicos para o scanner que você está usando